# How can I use a method created in a class to clean my Pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but for some reason I can't get the syntax right here.
I have a dataframe with a bunch of columns. I then created a class called DataCleaner that contains methods to clean said dataframe. Code is as follows:

```
class DataCleaner:
    """this class contains methods for removing possible outliers from a pandas dataframe"""
    def __init__(self, dataf):
        self.dataf=dataf

    def remove_upper_quantile(self, col, quantile_num):
        self.dataf=self.dataf[self.dataf[col]<self.dataf[col].quantile(quantile_num)]

    def remove_lower_quantile(self, col, quantile_num):
        self.dataf=self.dataf[self.dataf[col]>self.dataf[col].quantile(quantile_num)]

    def remove_nulls(self, col):
        self.dataf=self.dataf.dropna(subset=[col])
```

However, when I apply it using various approaches to a column in my df, I get the following message: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".

I've also tried the following (for context, target1 is one of the columns in my df):

```
myCleaner=DataCleaner(df)

myCleaner.remove_nulls(df.target1)
```

Which returns the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'target1'.

What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: `myCleaner.remove_null('target1')`, but it looks like `df` is a None` here?

Comment: I pass df as an argument to myCleaner when I create an instance of the class

Answer (score 0):

```
class DataCleaner:
    """this class contains methods for removing possible outliers from a pandas dataframe"""
    def __init__(self, dataf):
        self.dataf=dataf.copy()

    def remove_upper_quantile(self, col, quantile_num):
        self.dataf=self.dataf[self.dataf[col]<self.dataf[col].quantile(quantile_num)]

    def remove_lower_quantile(self, col, quantile_num):
        self.dataf=self.dataf[self.dataf[col]>self.dataf[col].quantile(quantile_num)]

    def remove_nulls(self, col: str):
        self.dataf[col].dropna(inplace=True)

myCleaner=DataCleaner(df)

myCleaner.remove_nulls('target1')
```

This should work